# Deploying a command line python program using Azure

Tags: web-services, amazon-web-services, azure, deployment, web-deployment

My question is specifically related to Azure OR AWS, ie. a cloud provider. So, please do not downvote.

I want to ask how can I deploy a commdn line program like:

https://github.com/rhiever/reddit-twitter-bot

which is written in python.

to the cloud?

I want the program to just run indefinitely, ie.e it will post data from reddit to twitter.

Can it be done with Azure, i know Azure provides for website deployment.

But for this, I think is there any service?

Or if I have to setup a Virtual machien and set up the code, how to configure my machine so that it posts data to twitter (are any networking issues associated)?

Sorry if the question is beginner, I have just started using cloud.

Comment: Almost every company that offers cloud services could be used for this, if you simply want 24x7 compute and networking. If you don't need it to run 24x7 but could run it, say, every 10 minutes then look at AWS Lambda or Azure Functions.

Comment: Why would you include "don't downvote"? Just curious, as it's superflous. However: As written, your question is off-topic as too broad: you're asking how to deploy, generically, to two different clouds. And there are *many* ways to deploy code, to *each* of the clouds you mentioned. There's no single answer for this, and there's no specific programming question, so this will end up getting you opinions (and possibly spam for a specific cloud, cloud service, or set of tools).

Answer (score 0):

If you were to choose AWS, you could run this easily within a docker container within Elastic Container Service (ECS). Look here for more information: [AWS ECS Features](https://aws.amazon.com/ecs/features/)

You can probably get what you want in the free tier.

Comment: Please don't answer such off-topic questions. There are potentially dozens (or hundreds) of answers for this type of question; it's far too broad, and there's simply no way to answer it objectively and definitively.